# Is a lightning arrestor required with a ground rod?

Tags: grounding, lightning

I am building an out building ham shack. I am planning to install an 8 foot ground rod for the antenna. Does the radio require an additional ground to the rod as well or do I need to install a lightning arrestor between the radio and the antenna coax?

Comment: Welcome! These sort of questions are best answered by studying a reference design for lightning protection, with all its notes, designing your system, and then asking for comments, rather than by asking questions like this one by one. It depends on so many things, each answer will give an opinion from a different direction, all correct but none of them useful to you. The lightning arrestor and earth rods are important, but they're just talismen if they're not installed as part of a well designed system. Start here: http://www.arrl.org/lightning-protection

Comment: Required for what purpose? To what specification?

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I will take under advisement the comments and do some additional research.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will explain lightning before giving my answer.

Lighting takes the path of least resistance, it dont matter whats it is. Lighting is a hammer, everything is a nail.

Your antenna is prime real estate for its path.

A. Its metal and it covers a good deal of surface area.

B. Its the quickest path to the ground.

So my answer is this:

Yes install the lighting arrestor but at the same time protect your equipment with additional measures like lighting rods that provides a straight forward path to the ground thats not your atenna It is better to be safe than sorry.

Because, lighting can hit that antenna and fry $$$$$ worth of equipment.

Comment: It's important to bear in mind lightning takes all paths in proportion to their resistance and, importantly, reactance.